# Unit testing a vue component and test not running, mount.context can only be used when mounting a functional component is the response

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, vuejs2, vue-test-utils

I am trying to unit test this vue component,

```
<template>
  <div
    class="toast toast--animate"
    :class="{
      'toast--error': this.type == 'error',
      'toast--success': this.type == 'success',
    }"
  >
    <div class="toast-content">{{ message }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Toast",
  props: {
    type: {
      type: String,
    },
    message: {
      type: String,
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.$store.commit("setNotification", {});
    }, 5500);
  },

  data() {
    return {};
  },
  computed: {},
};
</script>

<style scoped>
@keyframes movein {
  from {
    left: -500px;
  }
  to {
    left: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes moveout {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: -500px;
  }
}
.toast {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: -500px;
  transform: translateX(20px);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #dff0d8;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transition: left 0.5s ease;
}

.toast--animate {
  left: 0px;
}

.toast--animate-out {
  animation: moveout 0.5s ease forwards;
}

.toast--success {
  background-color: #4caf50;
}

.toast--error {
  background-color: #f44336;
}
</style>
```

This component is added my App.vue similar to this,

```
<template>
   <main>
     <vue-router />
     <Toast v-if="notification.type" :type="notification.type" :msg="notification.message" />
   </main>
</template>
```

It works absolutely fine in browser. However when I run this unit test,

```
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Toast from '../../common/Toast.vue';


describe('src/components/common/Toast.vue', () => {

    it('should render with an error class when an error notification is passsed too it', () => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(Toast, {
            context: {
                props: { type: 'error', message: 'This is an error message' },
            }
        });

        expect(wrapper.find('.toast--error').exitst()).toBeTruthy();
        expect(wrapper.find('.toast--success').exitst()).toBeFalsy();
    })

    it('should render with a success class when a success notification is passsed too it', () => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(Toast, {
            context: {
                props: { type: 'success', message: 'This is a success message' },
            }
        });

        expect(wrapper.find('.toast--success').exitst()).toBeTruthy();
        expect(wrapper.find('.toast--error').exitst()).toBeFalsy();
    });

    it('should render the appropriate message from the prop', () => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(Toast, {
            context: {
                props: { type: 'success', message: 'I am the notification content' },
            }
        });

        expect(wrapper.find('.toast-content').text()).toEqual('I am the notification content')
    });

    it('should destroy the component after 5.5 seconds', () => {
        jest.useFakeTimers();
        const wrapper = shallowMount(Toast, {
            context: {
                props: { type: 'success', message: 'I am the notification content' },
            }
        });
        jest.advanceTimersByTime(6000);
        expect(wrapper.find('.toast').exists()).toBeFalsy();
    });

});
```

I get the following error in my terminal,

> [vue-test-utils]: mount.context can only be used when mounting a functional component

I have tried using bother mount and shallowMount and it makes not difference.

Comment: Why is props located inside context? Should be propsData, no context, check how shallowMount is used

Comment: Yep this was the problem.

Comment: @EstusFlask can you add it as an answer? a lot of people ignore comments 

Answer (score 0):

`shallowMount` has `propsData` option, should be used instead of `context`:

```
    shallowMount(Toast, {
        propsData: { type: 'success', message: 'I am the notification content' }
    })
```